# In Debian, visudo /etc/sudoers

Tags: vim, debian, virtual-machine, sudoers

[image]

why is this line not highlighted?

```
Defaults authfail_message="message"
```

If it is okay not to be highlighted, I wonder what standard it is decided on.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, you have found a bug in an open source program.

The parameter `authfail_message` is indeed missing from [Vim's default syntax script](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/sudoers.vim#L229-L271) for `sudoers`.

Now, you have four options:

1. shrug it off,
2. or fix it locally and keep it for you (see `:help syntax`),
3. or contribute a fix as per [these guidelines](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/README.txt),
4. or open an issue in [Vim's issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) and let others deal with it.

If you go with 2, 3, or 4, consider checking if other parameters are missing.

Comment: And if you (the OP) do 3 or 4, please add a link to relevant branch / bug here, so that other users with same problem will see the status (and in which version it has been fixed, it will takes years before most distributions will include such version).

Comment: thank you for anwer
indeed, I'll DO